# Funcion recursiva en arbol binario php

Tags: php, algoritmos, estructuras-de-datos

Estoy resolviendo un ejercicio de algoritmos y estructura de datos donde se me pide que devuelva el valor máximo, mínimo y el promedio de valores de un árbol binario, con una función recursiva. Ya intenté utilizando los métodos para recorrer árboles (inorden, postorden y preorden), pero no logro utilizar los valores devueltos por la función para devolver el requerido.
Este sería el árbol en cuestión: (con un fallido intento de una función que devuelva el valor máximo)

```
class Node
{
    public $value;
    public $left; //Node object
    public $right; //Node Object

    public function __construct($v)
    {
        $this->value = $v;
        $this->left = null;
        $this->right = null;
    }
}

$root = new Node(20);
$root->left = new Node(3);
$root->left->left = new Node(10);
$root->left->right = new Node(5);
$root->left->right->left = new Node(4);
$root->left->right->right = new Node(33);
$root->right = new Node(13);
$root->right->right = new Node(7);
$root->right->right->left = new Node(23);
$root->right->right->right = new Node(1);

$valor = 0;

function maximo($arbol, $comparador)
{
    if(isset($arbol)){ //Chequea si $arbol != null
        if($comparador<$arbol){ //compara el valor inicial(0) con el valor inicial del nodo
        $comparador = $arbol->value; //si el mismo es mayor, la variable toma el valor del nodo
        }
        maximo($arbol->left, $comparador); //recursión por izquierda
        maximo($arbol->right, $comparador); //recursión por derecha
    }
    var_dump($comparador);
}
maximo($root, $valor);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El primer error que noto es que comparas la variable comparador con arbol, cuando debería ser con el value del árbol.
Además creo que el problema está en como usas la variable comparador, te recomendaría que utilices retornos en la función máximo, podrías hacer algo como:

```
function maximo($arbol, $comparador)
{
    if(isset($arbol)){ //Chequea si $arbol != null
        if($comparador<$arbol->value){ //compara el valor inicial(0) con el valor inicial del nodo
        $comparador = $arbol->value; //si el mismo es mayor, la variable toma el valor del nodo
        }
        maxDerecha := maximo($arbol->left, $comparador); //recursión por izquierda
        maxIzquierda := maximo($arbol->right, $comparador); //recursión por derecha
    }
    return valorMaximo(maxDerecha,maxIzquierda,comparador)
}
maximo($root, $valor);
```

Proba con una implementación parecida a esta, en la función valorMaximo deberias ver cual de los 3 valores es mayor para asi retornarlo.

Comment: En este artículo podes encontrar otra solución para tu problema https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-minimum-element-in-a-binary-search-tree/ .
Espero que te sirva!